# WARNING: All changes made in this file will be lost

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

So I have a general question. When you convert your .ui file into a .py file with pyuic, on the top part of the .py file it says:

**WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!**

Is is serious ? How will changes made in the file lost ?

I'm sorry I realise this is not a smart question but I just want to make sure what this is about and that it will not comprise anything afterwards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a generated file, it is a *result*, not a *source*. Thus:

1. When you distribute your project, you shouldn't be distributing that file. So, whatever you do to the file, won't reach your customers anyway.
2. Whenever your project is built and the source .ui file is changed, the output will be regenerated - and whatever changes you made to the output file, thus lost.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's much clearer now!
Well, since i don't intend to change the .ui file anymore it should be ok, and if i give both the .py and .ui files to somebody else, it should work right ?

Comment: @guy16 What you should give others is a makefile that takes the .ui and other sources and results in an installer or another deliverable. There's no point to distributing the .py file at all. When I download your product, I'd like to write `make` or `cmake` and get something that can run at the end (whether an executable for debugging, or an installer for distribution).

Answer (score 1):

What this means is: You’ve used a .uic file to generate a .py file, therefore if you modify the later manually ( i.e : create a class , or adding a comment etc...) and subsequently re-generate a file via puic those will be lost.
That’s why you should create a main.py file and import the generated .py file into it leaving the original untouched. 
If at a later stage you need to add a button and a label for example, you do so via qdesigner which gets you your new .uic file you create a .py
with the puic and voila your gui is modified your old .py erased by the new one but everything in your main.py stays the same.
Hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have generated .py file from the .ui file and will not be making any changes in the .ui file, changes will persist.